# ContentControl MouseDoubleClick event does not work when the content changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a DataTemplate like this:

```
    <!-- MULTI VIEW TEMPLATE -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiViewTemplate" >
        <Grid x:Name="MultiViewGrid" ShowGridLines="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BorderHwnd1}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MultiViewBorder1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="MultiViewBorder1_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BorderHwnd2}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MultiViewBorder2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="MultiViewBorder2_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BorderHwnd3}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MultiViewBorder3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="MultiViewBorder3_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BorderHwnd4}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MultiViewBorder4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="MultiViewBorder4_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the BorderHwnd1 is like this:

```
    <Border x:Key="BorderHwnd1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" >
        <Image Margin="1" Source="/MyProject;component/Images/No_image_available.png" />
    </Border>
```

My problem is that MultiViewBorder1_MouseDoubleClick event does not work after I remove and assign programmatically a new child to MultiViewBorder1. Initially MultiViewBorder1.Child is an image (No_image_available.png). In my code, I remove the image and assign a new child. This new child is a [HwndHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970061(v=vs.110).aspx).

Where is my mistake? any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. *"MultiViewBorder1_MouseDoubleClick event does not work"* -- exactly what do you mean, "does not work"? Exception? What? Please show us the handler and explain the symptoms. 2. *"after I remove and assign programmatically a new child to MultiViewBorder1"* --  that sentence could mean virtually anything. Show us the code. 3. You should be binding Content instead of setting it programmatically.

Comment: As a rule, it's a mistake to follow this form: *"Here's some code. It's fine. There's an error in some other code that I won't show you, but here's an incredibly vague description of how I felt about what I thought I was trying to accomplish when I wrote it. What's wrong?"*

Comment: MultiViewBorder1_MouseDoubleClick event does not work = MouseDoubleClick event not firing

`        private void onMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {        
            MessageBox.Show("Double Click");
        }`

Answer (score 1):

The child is changing from a WPF `Image` control....which is able to raise/flow "routed" "mouse" events through the visual tree....to some "hwnd" which you have inside the `HwndHost`, which is handling raw WIN32 mouses messages....and doesn't route them.

To be able to get mouse activity in your `HwndHost` into the visual tree, you could use a few different techniques to get them routed.

- have an overlayed "transparent" window
- handle the "mouse" messages in your WIN32/Hwnd, and then use "delegates" to raise

[How can I convert Win32 mouse messages to WPF mouse events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248643/how-can-i-convert-win32-mouse-messages-to-wpf-mouse-events)

[WPF WIN32 hwndhost WM_MOUSEMOVE WM_MOUSEHOVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516966/wpf-win32-hwndhost-wm-mousemove-wm-mousehover)